# I want run my visual studio in 64 bit mode

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, 32bit-64bit

I am writing my web service in .NET 3.5, in this I have to access SharePoint 2010 data, but SharePoint requires 64-bit mode for my application. Visual Studio by default in 32-bit mode. How can I run my Visual Studio 2013 in 64-bit?

This is what my task manager shows:
[image]

I think I need this to be 64-bit, what should I do now?

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/138661) and that running Visual Studio in 64 bit mode will not solve your problem. Why do you think that accessing Sharepoint 2010 data requires your *development environment* to run in 64 bit mode?

Comment: Visual Studio is a **32-bit** application - it cannot be run as a 64-bit app since no 64-bit version of Visual Studio exists.

Answer (score 8):

### Update 2021

[Microsoft just announced that Visual Studio 2022 will ship with a 64-bit version of the IDE so you can load super large solutions and won't constrain you to the 2GB limit imposed on 32-bit applications for visual studio itself.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511)

---

Visual Studio itself is a 32-bit application and cannot be run in "64-bit mode". However, Visual Studio can create both 32-bit and 64-bit applications and the debugger can connect to both types of executables .

There is no need for Visual Studio to run in a specific mode to do so, but it must run on a 64-bit capable computer, running the 64-bit version of windows.

It may be that your Visual Studio Project should be set to 64-bit or to AnyCPU for you to connect to SharePoint. To do so, set [the target platform of the project as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx).

> 1. On the menu bar, choose Build, Configuration Manager.
> 2. In the Active solution platform list, choose a 64-bit platform for the solution to target, and then choose the Close button.

> 1. If the platform that you want doesn’t appear in the Active solution platform list, choose New.
>    The New Solution Platform dialog box appears.
>    2. In the Type or select the new platform list, choose x64.
>    3. If you want to copy the settings from a current platform configuration, choose it, and then choose the OK button.

> **Note:**

> If you give your configuration a new name, you may have to modify the settings in the Project Designer to target the correct platform.

> The properties for all projects that target the 64-bit platform are updated, and the next build of the project will be optimized for 64-bit platforms.

Comment: I am running Visual Studio 2017 and it is still a 32-bit application. I really want to have it run in 64-bit mode because it will be able to use more RAM. Mine takes up to 1.8 GBs now. It becomes lagging after a week without a restart.

Comment: I understand that VS is 32bit application and that it can produce 32bit or 64bit executable. Also that debugged can connect to 32 or 64bit executable. However, within VS is there any way to debug the project in 64 bit mode (by using the debug button [green arrow])?

Comment: If the application is compiled as x64, it will be debugged as such. If the application is compiled as Any CPU, it will prefer x64, so that's the default. You can also configure your binary (through C# compiler settings), to be compiled as x64, but prefer x86: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/output?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#platformtarget Set platform to `anycpu32bitpreferred`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure VS actually can run as 64-bit, however you can run unit tests as a 64 bit process:

> **Running a unit test as a 64-bit process**
>
> To run a unit test as a 64-bit process
>
> If your code or tests were compiled as 32-bit/x86, but you now want to
>   run them as a 64-bit process, recompile them as Any CPU, or optionally
>   as 64-bit.
>
> **Tip:** For maximum flexibility, you should compile your test projects
>   with the Any CPU configuration. Then you can run on both 32 and 64 bit
>   agents. There is no advantage to compiling test projects with the
>   64-bit configuration.
>
> From the Visual Studio menu, choose Test, then choose Settings, and
>   then choose Processor Architecture. Choose x64 to run the tests as a
>   64-bit process.
>
> or
>
> Specify x64 in a .runsettings file.
>   An advantage of this method is that you can specify groups of settings
>   in different files and quickly switch between different settings. You
>   can also copy settings between solutions. For more information, see
>   Configuring Unit Tests by using a .runsettings File.

Taken from:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782531.aspx