# Oracle ODP.NET and Visual Studio: connection issue

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, odp.net

long time lurker and first time asking for help :)

We have a bug that keeps bothering us. We are unable to connect to an Oracle Database, from some Web Services with Visual Studio. We're currently using the unmanaged x64 Oracle.DataAccess.dll library (after getting some stranger issues with the Managed Driver).

It's a long and convoluted web service, but the point of failure is in this code:

```
protected virtual void PrepareCommand(IDbCommand command, IDbConnection connection, IDbTransaction transaction, CommandType commandType, string commandText, IDataParameter[] commandParameters, out bool mustCloseConnection)
        {
            if (command == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("command");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(commandText)) throw new ArgumentNullException("commandText");

            // If the provided connection is not open, we will open it
            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                mustCloseConnection = true;
                connection.Open(); // <-- here
            }
```

The connection object seems fine. Its ConnectionString property is as follows:

```
ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=_edited_)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=_edited_)));User Id=_edited_;Password=_edited_;"
```

This connection works perfectly from outside (Oracle SQL Developer access).

As soon as you call this method, an exception is generated, with the following properties:

```
Message = "Reference to an object not set as an instance of an object" <- Roughly translated by me, foreign IDE :(

StackTrace = "   en Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.get_Number()\r\n   en Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bChec...
```

Any help would be very appreciated. I've looked for other people's questions, but their solutions haven't worked for me. However, if this is a duplicate, please feel free to point me to the right direction. Thanks!! :)

EDIT: This is how we build the Connection object:

```
    using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
    ...
    using (OracleConnection oraConn = new OracleConnection(AdoFactory.Instance.Helper.GetConnection().ConnectionString))
                {
                    var newUser = **SessionDTO.GetSession**(token, oraConn);

                    AdoFactory.Instance.Usuario = newUser;

                    return newUser;
                }
    ...
    public static Usuario GetSession(string token, OracleConnection oraConn)
            {
                Usuario userActive = null;

                #region Parameters
                var m_paramToken = AdoFactory.Instance.Helper.GetParameter("p_TOKEN", token);
                #endregion

                var m_parameters = new[] { m_paramToken, AdoFactory.Instance.Helper.GetCursorForProcedure() };
                using (IDataReader reader = AdoFactory.Instance.Helper.**ExecuteReader**(oraConn,
                                                                        CommandType.StoredProcedure,"nameofprocedurewhichworksnicelyfromSQL",
                                                                        m_parameters))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
    ...
public IDataReader ExecuteReader(IDbConnection p_connection, CommandType p_commandType, string p_commandText, params IDataParameter[] p_commandParameters)
        {
            // Pass through the call to the private overload using a null transaction value and an externally owned connection
            return ExecuteReader(p_connection, null, p_commandType, p_commandText, p_commandParameters, AdoConnectionOwnership.External);
        }
...
private IDataReader ExecuteReader(IDbConnection p_connection, IDbTransaction p_transaction, CommandType p_commandType, string p_commandText, IDataParameter[] p_commandParameters, AdoConnectionOwnership p_connectionOwnership)
        {
            if (p_connection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("p_connection");

            var mustCloseConnection = false;
            // Create a command and prepare it for execution
            var cmd = p_connection.CreateCommand();
            try
            {
                **PrepareCommand**(cmd, p_connection, p_transaction, p_commandType, p_commandText, p_commandParameters, out mustCloseConnection);

                // Create a reader

                // Call ExecuteReader with the appropriate CommandBehavior
                var dataReader = p_connectionOwnership == AdoConnectionOwnership.External ? cmd.ExecuteReader() : cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                ClearCommand(cmd);
                return dataReader;
            }
            catch { 
                if (mustCloseConnection) p_connection.Close();
                throw;
            }
        }
```

ConnectionString: "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=asdf)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=asdf)));Enlist=true;User Id=asdf;Password=asdf;"

EDIT2: As suggested, I tried to open a plain OracleConnection and... it fails. The test:

```
// Simple test para ver si funciona crear una conexión normal de Oracle
        try
        {
            string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=asdf)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=asdf)));Enlist=true;User Id=asdf;Password=asdf;";
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);

            conn.Open(); // <-- fails here

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

            ......

            conn.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        ////////////////////////////////////////
```

The conn object:

```
    conn    {Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection} Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection
        CanRaiseEvents  true    bool
        CanRaiseEventsInternal  true    bool
        ConnectionCloseEvent    null    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.OracleConnectionCloseEventHandler
        ConnectionString    "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=--EDITED--)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=--EDITED--)));Enlist=true;User Id=--EDITED--;Password=--EDITED--;"   string
        ConnectionTimeout   15  int
        ConnectionType  Undefined   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnectionType
        Container   null    System.ComponentModel.IContainer
        DRCPConnectionClass null    string
        DRCPPurity  Pooled  Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.OracleDRCPPurity
        DataSource  "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=--EDITED--)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=--EDITED--)))"   string
        Database    ""  string
        DatabaseDomainName  ""  string
        DatabaseEditionName null    string
        DatabaseName    ""  string
+       DbProviderFactory   {Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory}  System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory {Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory}
        DesignMode  false   bool
+       Events  {System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList}    System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList
        ForceNewConnection  false   bool
        HostName    ""  string
        Identity    null    object
        InstanceName    ""  string
        IsDBVer10gR2OrHigher    false   bool
        IsDBVer11gR1OrHigher    false   bool
        IsDBVer11gR2OrHigher    false   bool
        IsDBVer12cR1OrHigher    false   bool
        IsDBVer_11_1_0_7_OrHigher   false   bool
        LogicalTransactionId    null    byte[]
+       OracleLogicalTransaction    {Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleLogicalTransaction} Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleLogicalTransaction
        PDBName ""  string
+       ProviderFactory {Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory}  System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory {Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory}
+       ServerVersion   'conn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'  string {System.InvalidOperationException}
        ServiceName ""  string
        Site    null    System.ComponentModel.ISite
        State   Closed  System.Data.ConnectionState
        StatementCacheSize  0   int
        SwitchedConnection  false   bool
+       TxnHndAllocated 'conn.TxnHndAllocated' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'   int {System.NullReferenceException}
        __identity  null    object
        _stateChangeEventHandler    null    System.Data.StateChangeEventHandler
        _supressStateChangeForReconnection  false   bool
+       events  {System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList}    System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList
+       listofWeakReferenceObj  Count = 0   System.Collections.Generic.List<System.WeakReference>
        lockOnWeakReferenceObjList  {object}    object
+       m_DataReaderList    Count = 0   System.Collections.ArrayList
        m_PatchSetVersion   0   int
        m_appEdition    null    string
        m_bCloseInProgress  false   bool
        m_bConnforTxnStatus false   bool
        m_bDrcpPurityNew    0   byte
        m_bErrorDoingErrorTranslation   false   bool
        m_bGetOutcome   false   bool
        m_bLocalTxnStartedForSysTxn false   bool
        m_bPrelimAuthSession    false   bool
        m_bSTFEnabled   false   bool
        m_bStartupShutdown  false   bool
        m_conOpenEventHandler   null    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnectionOpenEventHandler
        m_conSignature  0   int
+       m_conStrVals    {object[33]}    object[]
        m_conStrValsFromPool    false   bool
        m_conString "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=--EDITED--)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=--EDITED--)));Enlist=true;User Id=--EDITED--;Password=--EDITED--;"   string
        m_conTimeout    15  int
        m_contextConnection false   bool
        m_criteriaCtx   null    OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.CriteriaCtx
+       m_cs    {datasrc=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=--EDITED--)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=--EDITED--)));enlist=True;lifetime=0;maxsize=100;minsize=1;incsize=5;decsize=5;timeout=15;dbapriv=None;validcon=False;pooling=True;stmtcache=0;stmtcachepurge=0;metapool=True;selftuning=True;pspe=Promotable;ha=1;rlb=1;ac=1;userid=--EDITED--} OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.ConnectionString
        m_dataSource    "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=--EDITED--)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=--EDITED--)))"   string
        m_databaseDomainName    ""  string
        m_databaseName  ""  string
        m_disposed  false   bool
        m_drcpConnectionClass   null    string
        m_drcpPurity    Pooled  Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.OracleDRCPPurity
        m_enlist    0   int
        m_extProcEnv    null    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.ExtProcEnv
        m_failoverEventHandler  null    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleFailoverEventHandler
        m_hostName  ""  string
        m_id    null    string
        m_implId    0   int
+       m_implicitRefCursorCtxList  Count = 0   System.Collections.ArrayList
        m_infoMessageEventHandler   null    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInfoMessageEventHandler
        m_instanceName  ""  string
        m_internalConStr    "datasrc=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=--EDITED--)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=--EDITED--)));enlist=1;lifetime=0;maxsize=100;minsize=1;incsize=5;decsize=1;timeout=15;dbapriv=;validcon=0;stmtcache=0;stmtcachepurge=0;pooling=1;metapool=1;selftuning=1;pspe=promotable;ha=1;rlb=1;ac=1;userid=--EDITED--" string
        m_internalUse   false   bool
        m_isDb10gR2OrHigher false   bool
        m_isPuritySet   false   bool
+       m_lastEnlistedTransaction   null    System.Transactions.Transaction
        m_logicalTransaction    null    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleLogicalTransaction
        m_majorVersion  0   int
+       m_metaDataCollectionDS  null    System.Data.DataSet
        m_minorVersion  0   int
        m_newPassword   null    string
        m_openWithNewPwd    false   bool
+       m_opoConCtx {Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpoConCtx}    OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionImpl {Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpoConCtx}
+       m_oraGlobClone  null    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleGlobalization
        m_oraTransaction    null    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleTransaction
+       m_oracleConnectionImpl  null    OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionImpl
        m_orclPermission    null    Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OraclePermission
        m_password  "--EDITED--"    string
        m_pdbName   null    string
        m_persist   false   bool
        m_promoteTxnMgr null    OracleInternal.MTS.PSPETxnManagerBase
        m_proxyPassword ""  string
        m_pwdLessString "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=--EDITED--)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=--EDITED--)));Enlist=true;User Id=--EDITED--;"   string
        m_pwdOSLessString   "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=--EDITED--)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=--EDITED--)));Enlist=true;User Id=--EDITED--;"   string
        m_pwdValidated  false   bool
+       m_securePassword    null    System.Security.SecureString
+       m_secureProxyPassword   null    System.Security.SecureString
        m_serverVersion ""  string
        m_serviceName   ""  string
        m_sessionId 0   long
        m_state Closed  System.Data.ConnectionState
        m_stateChangeEventHandler   null    System.Data.StateChangeEventHandler
        m_stmtCacheSize 0   int
        m_syncTxnComplete   {object}    object
        m_tmpConString  null    string
        m_tuningLock    {object}    object
        m_userProvidedConEditionName    ""  string
        m_userProvidedPdbName   ""  string
        m_userProvidedServiceName   ""  string
        m_validConString    true    bool
+       pmCS    null    OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.ConnectionString
        site    null    System.ComponentModel.ISite
+       Static members
```

And the exception object:

```
    -       ex  {"Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto."} System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}
+       Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
        HResult -2147467261 int
        HelpLink    null    string
+       IPForWatsonBuckets  0x00007ffd87f6667a  System.UIntPtr
+       InnerException  null    System.Exception
        IsTransient false   bool
        Message "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto."   string
        RemoteStackTrace    null    string
        Source  "Oracle.DataAccess" string
        StackTrace  "   en Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.get_Number()\r\n   en Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable, OracleLogicalTransaction m_OracleLogicalTransaction)\r\n   en Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, Object src, OracleLogicalTransaction m_oracleLogicalTransaction)\r\n   en Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnectionOCP.Open(OracleConnection con)\r\n   en Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()\r\n   en UNED.FP.BL.OAuth.OAuth.ValidateToken(String token) en --EDITED--"  string
+       TargetSite  {Int32 get_Number()}    System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
        WatsonBuckets   null    object
        _HResult    -2147467261 int
        _className  null    string
+       _data   {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
        _dynamicMethods null    object
+       _exceptionMethod    {Int32 get_Number()}    System.Reflection.MethodBase {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}
        _exceptionMethodString  null    string
        _helpURL    null    string
+       _innerException null    System.Exception
+       _ipForWatsonBuckets 0x00007ffd87f6667a  System.UIntPtr
        _message    "Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto."   string
        _remoteStackIndex   0   int
        _remoteStackTraceString null    string
+       _safeSerializationManager   {System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager} System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager
        _source "Oracle.DataAccess" string
+       _stackTrace {sbyte[384]}    object {sbyte[]}
        _stackTraceString   null    string
        _watsonBuckets  null    object
        _xcode  -532462766  int
+       _xptrs  0x0000000000000000  System.IntPtr
+       Static members
```

Comment: Obviously the connection object is not fine - otherwise you would not get an error. Visual Studio is 32-bit, thus you cannot debug your program if you have (only) the x64 Oracle.DataAccess.dll installed. Did you compile your program as x64 (or AnyCPU)?

Comment: It seems they can be debugged indeed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686462/i-want-run-my-visual-studio-in-64-bit-mode And yes, it's compiled as x64 (previously AnyCPU, but tried to force it to 64bit anyways) :)

Comment: You are right, I missed that. In VS2012 you have the limitation that you cannot edit the code while debugging in x64 mode, there I mixed it.

Comment: How do you create the Connection object? Note, SQL Developer is based on Java which is completely independent from access via ODP.NET (Oracle.DataAccess.dll)

Comment: Added info in the original question :)

Comment: You don't call `PrepareCommand()` in your code. If you use `using () {}` then the object is disposed when it leaves the block. Thus Connection object is not valid when you try to open.

Comment: We call it. Edited again to show it.

Comment: Maybe try to open a simple plain OracleConnection as given in hundreds of tutorials and tutorials. Then you would know at least whether the problem is at your code or the Oracle Client installation.

Comment: I tried and it fails too, so the problem must be on the Oracle part. Edited again. Hey, and thanks for your time ;)

Comment: Which Oracle clients and components did you install?

Comment: I downloaded and installed http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html 12.2.0.1.0 64 bit, Basic Package. Following second answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105863/oracle-connection-open-error-when-connecting-from-net-code, I copied and pasted the code to C:\oracle\bin.

At this point, the "test" connection does not fail, but the real code does.

Comment: You should remove all of them and download the client from [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/tools/index-090165.html).

Comment: But this is the Managed version, and we faced some strange, random errors while retrieving data (the connection itself could be established with no issues). Can't we use the unmanaged x64 version??

Comment: `ODAC122010Xcopy_x64.zip` contains the unmanaged ODP.NET, download this.

Comment: Downloaded and installed. Some "access denied" error, however files seem to be decompressed into c:\oracle. 

C:\...\Downloads\ODAC122010Xcopy_x64>install.bat all c:\oracle odac
ERROR: Acceso denegado.
ERROR: Acceso denegado.
ERROR: Acceso denegado.
ERROR: Acceso denegado.
ERROR: Acceso denegado.
ERROR: Acceso denegado.
ERROR: Acceso denegado.
ERROR: Acceso denegado.

Same error as before.

Comment: Verify the folder permissions for "execute". Try `ICACLS c:\Oracle /reset /T /C /L`

Comment: What do you get from `conn.GetType().Assembly.Location` and `conn.GetType().Assembly.FullName`?

Comment: Have Full Control and Read and Execute permissions in c:\oracle.

ICALCS returns a bunch of processed files: archivo procesado: c:\Oracle
archivo procesado: c:\Oracle\adrci.exe.................

  location "C:\\WINDOWS\\Microsoft.Net\\assembly\\GAC_64\\Oracle.DataAccess\\v4.0_4.122.1.0__89b483f429c47342\\Oracle.DataAccess.dll" string
  fullName "Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.122.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" string

Comment: Difficult to say what is wrong when I have no access. Perhaps you have to run a full cleanup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450726/how-to-uninstall-completely-remove-oracle-11g-client